# aligning image in center

Tags: html, css

I want to align images in center as four in top and and three in bottom which is in same div.

```css
.tiles-menu{
  width:1024px;
  margin:auto;
}
.tiles-menu .submenu-menu .views-row{
  float:left; 
}
.tilesImage , .tilesTitle{
  margin:auto;
}
.innerPageTilesMenu{
  padding:4%;
}
```

```html
<div id="tiles_menu">
  <div class="view view-tiles-menu view-id-tiles_menu view-display-id-block view-dom-id-bdffce08b72061133c0ad959070833a3">
    <div class="view-content">
      <div class="tiles-menu">
        <div class="submenu-menu nav navbar-nav main-menu" style=""> 
          <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
            <a href="http://localhost/AspireInnerWebsite/services/retail/Consulting&amp;Solutions/Omnichannel">
              <div class="innerPageTilesMenu">
                <div class="tilesImage">
                  <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/AspireInnerWebsite/sites/default/files/tab-strategic-store-solutions.jpg" alt="" width="235" height="228">
                </div>
                <div class="tilesTitle"><p>Omnichannel</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a> 
          </div>
          <div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">
            <a href="http://localhost/AspireInnerWebsite/services/retail/Consulting&amp;Solutions/Strategic-Store-Solutions">
              <div class="innerPageTilesMenu">
                <div class="tilesImage">
                  <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/AspireInnerWebsite/sites/default/files/tab-omnichannel_0.jpg" alt="" width="235" height="228">
                </div>
                <div class="tilesTitle"><p>Strategic Store Solutions</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd">
            <a href="http://localhost/AspireInnerWebsite/services/retail/Consulting&amp;Solutions/Merchandise-Operations">
              <div class="innerPageTilesMenu">
                <div class="tilesImage">
                  <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/AspireInnerWebsite/sites/default/files/tab-Merchandise-Operations.jpg" alt="" width="235" height="228"></div>
                <div class="tilesTitle"><p>Merchandise Operation</p></div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="views-row views-row-4 views-row-even">
            <a href="http://localhost/AspireInnerWebsite/services/retail/Consulting&amp;Solutions/Retail-Supply-Chain">
              <div class="innerPageTilesMenu">
                <div class="tilesImage">
                  <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/AspireInnerWebsite/sites/default/files/tab-Retail-Supply-Chain.jpg" alt="" width="235" height="228"></div>
                <div class="tilesTitle"><p>Retail Supply Chain</p></div>
              </div>
            </a> 
          </div>
          <div class="views-row views-row-5 views-row-odd">
            <a href="http://localhost/AspireInnerWebsite/services/retail/Consulting&amp;Solutions/Predictive-Analytics">
              <div class="innerPageTilesMenu">
                <div class="tilesImage">
                  <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/AspireInnerWebsite/sites/default/files/tab-Predictive-Analytics.jpg" alt="" width="235" height="228"></div>
                <div class="tilesTitle"><p>Predictive Analytics</p></div>
              </div>
            </a> 
          </div>
          <div class="views-row views-row-6 views-row-even">
            <a href="http://localhost/AspireInnerWebsite/services/retail/Consulting&amp;Solutions/Retail-Test-Automation">
              <div class="innerPageTilesMenu">
                <div class="tilesImage">
                  <img typeof="foaf:Image"                src="http://localhost/AspireInnerWebsite/sites/default/files/tab-Retail-Test-Automation.jpg" alt="" width="235" height="228"></div>
                <div class="tilesTitle"><p>Retail Test Automation</p></div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="views-row views-row-7 views-row-odd views-row-last">
            <a href="http://localhost/AspireInnerWebsite/services/retail/Consulting&amp;Solutions/Digital-Services">
              <div class="innerPageTilesMenu">
                <div class="tilesImage">
                  <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/AspireInnerWebsite/sites/default/files/tab-digital-services.jpg" alt="" width="235" height="228"></div>
                <div class="tilesTitle"><p>Digital Services</p></div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For some purpose I have all the images in single div. I want as shown in star

```
*  *  *  *
  *  *  *
```

I have created fiddle [**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/f9cbjmge/1/)

Comment: use `inline:block` for children elements and have a text-align center for parent element.

Comment: where to add inline:block.can you five fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/f9cbjmge/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use css3 [**`flexbox`**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Consider the following css:

```
.main-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```css
.tiles-menu {
  width:1024px;
  margin:auto;
}
.tiles-menu .submenu-menu .views-row {
  float:left; 
}
.tilesImage , .tilesTitle{margin:auto;}
.innerPageTilesMenu{padding:4%;}

.main-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="tiles_menu">
  <div class="view view-tiles-menu view-id-tiles_menu view-display-id-block view-dom-id-bdffce08b72061133c0ad959070833a3">
    <div class="view-content">
      <div class="tiles-menu"><div class="submenu-menu nav navbar-nav main-menu" style="">  <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
        <a href="http://localhost/AspireInnerWebsite/services/retail/Consulting&amp;Solutions/Omnichannel">
          <div class="innerPageTilesMenu">
            <div class="tilesImage"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/AspireInnerWebsite/sites/default/files/tab-strategic-store-solutions.jpg" alt="" width="235" height="228"></div>
            <div class="tilesTitle"><p>Omnichannel</p></div>
          </div>
        </a>  </div>
        <div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">
          <a href="http://localhost/AspireInnerWebsite/services/retail/Consulting&amp;Solutions/Strategic-Store-Solutions">
            <div class="innerPageTilesMenu">
              <div class="tilesImage"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/AspireInnerWebsite/sites/default/files/tab-omnichannel_0.jpg" alt="" width="235" height="228"></div>
              <div class="tilesTitle"><p>Strategic Store Solutions</p></div>
            </div>
          </a>  </div>
        <div class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd">
          <a href="http://localhost/AspireInnerWebsite/services/retail/Consulting&amp;Solutions/Merchandise-Operations">
            <div class="innerPageTilesMenu">
              <div class="tilesImage"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/AspireInnerWebsite/sites/default/files/tab-Merchandise-Operations.jpg" alt="" width="235" height="228"></div>
              <div class="tilesTitle"><p>Merchandise Operation</p></div>
            </div>
          </a>  </div>
        <div class="views-row views-row-4 views-row-even">
          <a href="http://localhost/AspireInnerWebsite/services/retail/Consulting&amp;Solutions/Retail-Supply-Chain">
            <div class="innerPageTilesMenu">
              <div class="tilesImage"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/AspireInnerWebsite/sites/default/files/tab-Retail-Supply-Chain.jpg" alt="" width="235" height="228"></div>
              <div class="tilesTitle"><p>Retail Supply Chain</p></div>
            </div>
          </a>  </div>
        <div class="views-row views-row-5 views-row-odd">
          <a href="http://localhost/AspireInnerWebsite/services/retail/Consulting&amp;Solutions/Predictive-Analytics">
            <div class="innerPageTilesMenu">
              <div class="tilesImage"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/AspireInnerWebsite/sites/default/files/tab-Predictive-Analytics.jpg" alt="" width="235" height="228"></div>
              <div class="tilesTitle"><p>Predictive Analytics</p></div>
            </div>
          </a>  </div>
        <div class="views-row views-row-6 views-row-even">
          <a href="http://localhost/AspireInnerWebsite/services/retail/Consulting&amp;Solutions/Retail-Test-Automation">
            <div class="innerPageTilesMenu">
              <div class="tilesImage"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/AspireInnerWebsite/sites/default/files/tab-Retail-Test-Automation.jpg" alt="" width="235" height="228"></div>
              <div class="tilesTitle"><p>Retail Test Automation</p></div>
            </div>
          </a>  </div>
        <div class="views-row views-row-7 views-row-odd views-row-last">
          <a href="http://localhost/AspireInnerWebsite/services/retail/Consulting&amp;Solutions/Digital-Services">
            <div class="innerPageTilesMenu">
              <div class="tilesImage"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/AspireInnerWebsite/sites/default/files/tab-digital-services.jpg" alt="" width="235" height="228"></div>
              <div class="tilesTitle"><p>Digital Services</p></div>
            </div>
          </a>  </div>
        </div></div>
    </div>






  </div></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Updated your css as. It should fix your issue.

```
.tiles-menu {
    text-align: center;
}
.tiles-menu .submenu-menu .views-row {
    //float: left; **remove this code**
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rx4hvn/f9cbjmge/2/)